# AWS reading utf-8 file pycaption.detect_format returns None

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, pycaption

Python version: 3.5-slim-buster
Module: pycaption

When reading caption .srt that is us-ascii encoded from s3 bucket:

```
obj.get()['Body'].read()
print(pycaption.detect_format(body.decode()))
```

I get a desired response

```
<class 'pycaption.srt.SRTReader'>
```

But when reading utf-8 encoded s3 .srt file

pycaption can't detect format response:

```
None
```

I have tried:

```
obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')

print(pycaption.detect_format(body))
```

But with no luck

Answer (score 0):

In the end the issue was in DOS newlines CR/LF that I converted to DOS newlines CR/LF.